# Is it possible to modify the response content through Scrapy Selector?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to deep copy some content on one page, to crawl the content and download the images in that content and update the image original value accordingly.

For example I have:

```
<div class="A">
    <img original="example1.com/1/1.png"></img>
</div>
```

I need to download the image and update the new image original value（for example to mysite.com/1/1.png）, then save the content.

what I will have finally is:

```
<div class="A">
    <img original="mysite.com/1/1.png"></img>
</div>
```

and image on my disk.

Is it possible to modify the value through Selector?

Or must I download the image first and update the "original" value separately? any better solution?

Comment: After downloading, what do you need to do with the image path?

Comment: I need to update the content that refers to the image, the new image path on disk will be based on the original value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the reply from scrapy dev.

[Is it possible to modify the response content through Scrapy Selector?](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/issues/36)

```
No.

Selectors are meant to address parts of a document, not to transform it.
Although some elementary things are possible,
like striping namespaces and running a regex over a string result,
transformations are out of the scope of this project for now
(and practically they will remain so in the near future).

You should look into xslt or some similar technology.
```